# PHP getting data in an array with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, web

I'm working on a graph for my website. I want to show different data in this graph. 
I have a mysql database with a table with four rows. 
I want to save these four rows in an array, this array will be visible on the graph.

```
$transportertraindb = mysql_query("SELECT container_counter FROM transporter WHERE transporter_name = 'trein'", $db);
$transporterlorrydb = mysql_query("SELECT container_counter FROM transporter WHERE transporter_name = 'vrachtauto'", $db);
$transporterinlanddb = mysql_query("SELECT container_counter FROM transporter WHERE transporter_name = 'binnenschip'", $db);
$transporterseadb = mysql_query("SELECT container_counter FROM transporter WHERE transporter_name = 'zeeschip'", $db);
```

This are the rows in my database. i'm saving the value of them in a variable.

```
$data = array('Zeeschip'=>$transporterseadb, 'Binnenvaart'=>$transporterinlanddb, 'Trein'=>$transportertraindb, 'Vrachtwagen'=>$transporterlorrydb);
```

And this will be my array.

Unfortunately, this does not give the desired result. because all values are equal in the graphics, I think this is because he does not get the right data. I guess I did something wrong in my code, and i hope someone can help me with this problem.

Below you will find the whole graph code, well i wont copy the included page..

```
 <?php
include('graidlechart/graidle.php');
    / array with number of tourists, by countries
    $data = array('Zeeschip'=>$transporterseadb, 'Binnenvaart'=>$transporterinlanddb, 'Trein'=>$transportertraindb, 'Vrachtwagen'=>$transporterlorrydb);        


    // set 2 numeric arrays, one with countries (for legend), another with tourists number
    $cnt = array_keys($data);
    $tor = array_values($data);

    // create object of graidle class (define Title)
    $graph = new graidle('Representation containers of transporters');
    $graph->setColor('#a7b8ed');
    $graph -> setValue($tor,'p');      // set pie chart (p=pie)

    $graph -> setLegend($cnt);             // to add a legend
    $graph -> setExtLegend(1);             // to display percentage, and numbers
    $graph -> setWidth(420);               // graphic chart width

    $graph -> create();                       // create chart
    $graph->carry2file('charts/', 'graphic_chart_3');
    ?>
```

Comment: Where are you fetching the resultset from the database? Are you using `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` anywhere before assigning the array values? And `mysql_*` is vulnerable code.

Comment: You should use mysql_fetch_array

Comment: @BeatAlex No: `mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`

Comment: @lolka_bolka Sorry you're right!

Comment: No problem, just do not want to confuse the OP.

Comment: I would suggest you look at using a stored procedure instead of having multiple selects, you can create one call to a stored procedure which can run as may DB queries as you want and return the values you need and then you can parse the returned data as needed. It will help reduce the load on the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fetch datas.

```
$transportertraindb = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT container_counter FROM transporter WHERE transporter_name = 'trein'", $db));
$transporterlorrydb = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT container_counter FROM transporter WHERE transporter_name = 'vrachtauto'", $db));
$transporterinlanddb = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT container_counter FROM transporter WHERE transporter_name = 'binnenschip'", $db));  
$transporterseadb = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT container_counter FROM transporter WHERE transporter_name = 'zeeschip'", $db));
$data = array('Zeeschip'=>$transporterseadb['container_counter'], 'Binnenvaart'=>$transporterinlanddb['container_counter'], 'Trein'=>$transportertraindb['container_counter'], 'Vrachtwagen'=>$transporterlorrydb['container_counter']);
```

I hope it helps.